# vue component does not load methods?

Tags: vue.js

I tried to use same vue form component for
"add"-mode and "edit" -mode to void make same form twice.

Logic goes this way:

- Main component 'History' loads data from back-end (Laravel)
  if data exist loads 'list' component and pass data via props
  and mode is 'edit'.

  If there is no data loads form and mode is 'add'.

history.vue

```
<div v-if = "this.educations.length >0 ">
   Status: {{ status }}
   <list :educations="educations" :mode="mode.editvalue"> </list>
</div>
<div v-else>
   <eduform :mode ="mode.addvalue"> </eduform>
</div>
```

- This part simple and works ok.
- inside the eduform-component, I have two button and they are showing depends mode.

`v-show="mode === 'add'"` or `v-show="mode === 'edit'"`

The problem is in my form: it killed my methods totally!

`<form  @submit.prevent="mode === 'add' ?  createEdu() :  updateEdu() ">`

Here is my method:

```
createEdu() {
  console.log(this.mode);
  this.axios
    .post(`/api/education/add/`, this.education)
    .then((response) => {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'education'
      })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

What's wrong in this code?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that you use twice the same component in the same parent-component? If is like this, try to add name to your component.

Comment: `mode.addvalue` is not equal to `add` and `mode.editvalue` is not equal to `edit`

Comment: `Problem is in my form, it killed my methods totally!` - what does it mean? Are the not being executed? As posted, everything should work so the issue must lie somewhere else. (Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mqzk54j/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal opinion is: avoid tenary operators in your templates whenever possible. Instead of conditionally binding a method to your `submit` event, you should simply bind a generic method to the submit event. In the generic method itself you will then perform whatever checks that is necessary in order to invoke the appropriate callback. This makes your template way more readable, and abstracts complicated logic into the JS part of your VueJS component.

Example:

```
<form @submit.prevent="onFormSubmit">
```

Then, in the JS part of your component, you can do:

```
onFormSubmit() {
  if (this.mode === 'add')
    this.createEdu();
  else
    this.updateEdu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis from your call of the methods. I believe when your adding a method as an event handler that is the correct way to handle it.

Its explained better here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/difference-when-calling-a-method-function-with-or-without-brackets/41764/2

Comment: There should be no difference here, as the function expects no arguments.